# Accessing variables names from a list in python

Tags: python, list

I'm working with python and I was just wondering that is it possible to have variable names be stored in another list.

```
Achievement = ['hi', 'hey', 'hello']
lines = ['Achievement', 'hi']
print lines[0][2]
```

I want the output to be **'hello'** in this case.
Can anyone suggest me any way to achieve that.

Comment: use of dictionary would be the correct thing here

Comment: You could store variable (not variable name) in another list. 
`lines = [Achievement, 'hi']`

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes here. It is not a bad question per se, even if the idea is quite bad.

Comment: @glglgl I'm guessing lack of effort

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do variable variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually if you want to dynamically lookup names in Python code, correct solution is to use mapping. In Python basic mapping object is dictionary. Sample code which does what you want may be following:

```
d = {'Achievement': ['hi', 'hey', 'hello']}
key = 'Achievement'
index = 2
print d[key][index]
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible, yes. You can do so by accessing `globals()` and/or `locals()` and using their result (which is a dict of varname: varcontent).

But that's very bad style as you can read [here](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.de/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).

There are much better ways of doing so, including

```
Achievement = ['hi', 'hey', 'hello']
lines = [Achievement, 'hi']
print lines[0][2]
```

or using a dict or other things.

Answer (score 1):

But if you really wanted to do this

**code:**

```
 d=globals()
 d[lines[0]][2]
```

**output:**

```
 'hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Achievement = ['hi', 'hey', 'hello']
lines = ['Achievement', 'hi']
print eval(lines[0])[2]
```

Comment: Using `eval` is generally bad practice. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/3087339)